# Play looping audio using AudioTrack

Tags: android, audiotrack

I have a feature I want to transition over to use Androids `AudioTrack` instead of `MediaPlayer`, due to a few well known bugs with `MediaPlayer`, such as the small gap that appears between looping tracks.

I've been recommended to use `AudioTrack` but haven't found to many examples of it in use. I did find a question on SO regarding `AudioTrack` and used some of that code to hack together something:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

    Button playButton;
    byte[] byteData = null;
    int bufSize;
    AudioTrack myAT = null;
    Thread playThread = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.whitenoise_wav);
        try {
            byteData = new byte[ inputStream.available()];
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            inputStream.read(byteData);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        initialize();

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                playThread.start();
            }
        });
    }

    void initialize() {

        bufSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        myAT = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        myAT.setVolume(.2f);

        playThread = new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        if (myAT != null) {
            myAT.play();
            myAT.setLoopPoints(0, byteData.length, 6);
            myAT.write(byteData, 0, byteData.length);
        }
    }
}
```

So this does seem to play the entire audio track (~1:00 min) and then stops. Now the end goal here is two have 2 seperate audio tracks playing and looping at the same time. I currently have the audio tracks in the `/res/raw/` directory, but I can move them to a simple `assets` folder if that would be better. Is my current implementation of `AudioTrack` correct? If so, how would I get it to loop?

In summation: how can you play looping audio without a gap using `AudioTrack`?

Suggestions for alternative ways to get looping audio, such as third party libraries, are welcomed.

Comment: Are you want to play the both tracks at same time and also loop that audio once finish right ?

Comment: Check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Comment: `SoundPool` is primarily for short clips, lasting only a few seconds, like game sound effects.

Answer (score 8):

You can't loop using an AudioTrack configured with `AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM`. If you use `MODE_STREAM` AudioTrack needs to be filled with new samples continuously.

But you can configure it with `AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC` and pass the entire buffer to be played (I mean: if you need to mix two samples, you have to pass the mixed samples).

> setLoopPoints: Sets the loop points and the loop count. The loop can be infinite. Similarly to setPlaybackHeadPosition, the track must be stopped or paused for the loop points to be changed, and must use the MODE_STATIC mode.

Please note that AudioTrack plays raw PCM samples, there's no support for WAV, MP3 or other containers.

Comment: If the file is stored in your raw resources, you can return an `InputStream` when getting the resource and feed that into the `AudioTrack`. By looping, I mean any way to properly loop it, whether it be feeding it data continuously or feeding it once and auto looping, it simply cannot have a gap.

Comment: I understand what your saying, I know that auto looping with `.setLoopingPoints()` can only be done in static mode. I was looking for an example of gapless looping with either `MODE_STATIC` and/or `MODE_STREAM` as most examples I have come across were not really working. I played around with it a bit and got a working implementation using static mode and `.setLoopingPoints`, though it sometimes studders during playback. I also noticed that if its not played in a new thread, it will produce a loud starting sound on startup, and then fall silent. Is playing on the main thread an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797997/looping-an-audio-file) example, it seems a similar issue, solved feeding continuously the `AudioTrack`.

```
class ToneGenerator {
    int sampleRate = 8000;
    double sample[] = null;
    byte generatedSnd[] = null;
    int m_ifreq = 400;
    Thread m_PlayThread = null;
    boolean m_bStop = false;
    AudioTrack m_audioTrack = null;
    int m_play_length = 1000;//in seconds

    static public void PlayTone(int freq, int play_length) {
        ToneGenerator player = new ToneGenerator();
        player.m_ifreq = freq;
        player.m_play_length = play_length;
        player.play();
    }

    synchronized void stop() {
        m_bStop = true;
        if (m_PlayThread != null) {
            try {
                m_PlayThread.interrupt();
                m_PlayThread.join();
                m_PlayThread = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        if (m_audioTrack != null) {
            m_audioTrack.stop();
            m_audioTrack.release();
            m_audioTrack = null;
        }
    }

    synchronized void play() {
        m_bStop = false;
        m_PlayThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int iToneStep = 0;

                    m_audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 2 * sampleRate,
                            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                    while (!m_bStop && m_play_length-- > 0) {
                        genTone(iToneStep++);

                        m_audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
                        if (iToneStep == 1) {
                            m_audioTrack.play();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Tone", e.toString());
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    Log.e("Tone", e.toString());
                }

            }
        };
        m_PlayThread.start();
    }

    //Generate tone data for 1 seconds
    synchronized void genTone(int iStep) {
        sample = new double[sampleRate];

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleRate; ++i) {
            sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (i + iStep * sampleRate) / (sampleRate / m_ifreq));
        }

        // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
        // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
        generatedSnd = new byte[2 * sampleRate];
        int idx = 0;
        for (final double dVal : sample) {
            // scale to maximum amplitude
            final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
            // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why 2 * sampleRate?

Comment: Because of 16bit sampling, so you do 8 * 2

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in byte length of the stream.  setLoopPoints() expects the number of audio blocks in the stream.  See getBufferSizeInFrames() in the documentation.

However.  I caution you that most particular audio formats are not block based; they are sample based.  MP3 is the sole exception; it is aligned on 1152 byte boundaries.  If the source content is MP3 and not explicitly authored to be block aligned, seamless looping is impossible.  You seem to be using "whitenoise.wav" as your audio source.  Unless the length of this file is explicitly aligned to block size, you may have audio artifacts when looping.

The workaround for this is to cross-fade the beginning and final frame blocks when you loop, and handle all the buffering yourself, but you'd have to write code to do this yourself.